# How to get QuerySet as TextChoice in Django

Tags: django, django-models

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 


class ZutatenHinzufügen(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=15, name="Zutat")
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, name="Menge")
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="Hinzugefügt durch")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, name="Hinzugefügt am")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient
```

How can I get the QuerySet "title" of the ShoppingList class as input for

```
list=models.TextChoice(...)
```

I tried ShoppingList.objects.all() but there comes an Error called it ist not possible to take this as a TextChoice

Comment: Please use a `ForeignKey`. This is not something for a model, this is the *widget* for a *form*.

Comment: But what ist the right code for geting the values of ShoppingList.title into the class ZutatenHinzufügen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Willem Van Onsem is suggesting this:

```
class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 


class ZutatenHinzufügen(models.Model):
    shopping_list = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=15, name="Zutat")
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, name="Menge")
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name="Hinzugefügt durch")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, name="Hinzugefügt am")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient
```

Now you can do:

```
obj = ZutatenHinzufügen.objects.get()
obj.shopping_list.title
```